# jsonb_set function in postgresql 9.4 fails

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

i have the following column `configuration` which stores a large amount of information in a jsonb datatype. The column in my table looks like this:

```
select configuration -> 'object'-> 0 FROM my_table;
               ?column?
--------------------------------------------
[{"resources": {"r1": 1, "r2": 2, "r3": 3}]
```

I'm trying to update the value `r3` with the `jsonb_set` function in this way:

```
update my_table 
set configuration = jsonb_set(configuration::jsonb, '{object,0,resources,r3}::text[]', jsonb '6')
```

The path looks correct, and the data type as well. Anyway, Im getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], jsonb) does not exist
```

Are the data types still not correct? How can I make it work? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `jsonb_set()` was introduced in 9.5, so you can't use it in 9.4 But as Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) this is a perfect moment to do your upgrade to 12

Comment: ah I thought it as introduced in 9.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved, as a_horse_with_no_name said is not possible to use that function in postgres 9.4!